# Function returns undefined despite console.log showing value before return

Tags: node.js, function, async-await, axios, return

I am trying to return an array via axios call from an async function in node js.
The axios call works correctly, and console.log shows me the array I am looking for in the data object of the returned promise.
But when I use console.log to see the result of the function outside the function, it shows "undefined".

```
async function userImport (settings, file) {
let usersFile;
const auth = {
          "username": settings.authentication.user,
          "password": settings.authentication.password
        };
        const options = {
          method: 'get',
          headers: {

          },
          timeout: 10000
        };
        await axios.get(settings.url,auth,options)
        .then((results) => {
usersFile = results.data;
          console.log(usersFile);
          if (usersFile && usersFile != "" && usersFile != undefined) {
            console.log("Test1");
            return [usersFile,settings.encoding];
          } else {
            console.log("Test2");
            return results;
          }
})
}

await userImport(settings, file)
        .then(async (users)=>{
          console.log(users);
})
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
[{...},{...},{...}] //The array I'm looking for
Test1
Undefined
```

What I expected to get is:

```
[{...},{...},{...}] //The array I'm looking for
Test1
[{...},{...},{...}] //The array I'm looking for
```

I tried putting the array into a json object like this:

```
let usersFile = {};
usersFile.users = results.data;
```

then I get:

```
{users:[{...},{...},{...}]} //The array I'm looking for
Test1
Undefined
```

I also tried returning results.data directly without putting it in an element, but the results were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this issue, I finally figured it out.
The issue is with the use of

```
.then((results)
```

Because I am calling another function, the "return" was sent for it instead of the outer function, so the outer one finished without a "return".

There were two solutions to this issue:

1. (the one I picked) change the structure to not use .then in the following way:

   usersFile = await axios.get(settings.url,auth,options);
   usersFile = usersFile.data;
2. Add another return with the results of the inner function.